# Drop down box is always 100%

Tags: html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="30px;">
  <table width="100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <SELECT name="guidelinks">
          <OPTION SELECTED value="jex6.htm">Page 1
          <OPTION value="jex7.htm">My Cool Page
        </SELECT> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

When this drop down box is displayed the width is 100%, not 30px, can anyone explain why and how to fix this?

Unofrtunatly I cant edit the code on the CSS

Comment: You probably don't even need to house it in a div and a table, but this might be a snippet of something larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to give a specific `width` to the select element itself ..

```
<select style="width:30px;" name="guidelinks">...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in  your div's style tag:

```
<div style="30px;">
```

should be

```
<div style="width:30px;">
```

30px is a VERY narrow width, mind you. I would make it at least 5 times wider.